# Reactのコンポーネント化がされない

Tags: reactjs

#### 前提

現在ポートフォリオサイトを作成しています。
https://github.com/takoyan33/manga-kousatu.net
https://mangakousatunet.vercel.app/

#### 実現したいこと

現在ポートフォリオで作成している
このカード部分をコンポーネント化したいと考えています。
https://mangakousatunet.vercel.app/home

データはFirestoreから取得しており、
mapで表示しています。

[image: イメージ説明]

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

ですが、ファイルを２つに分けて、cardpost.jsを作り、コンポーネント化しようとしたのですが、
上手くコンポーネント化されずに、
真っ白なカード部分が6個表示されているという状態です。
原因がまだわかっていないのですが、記述ミスなどでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

[image: イメージ説明]

#### 該当のソースコード

```
#Cardpost.jsx
import省略

export const Cardpost = (
  downloadURL,
  id,
  title,
  categori,
  netabare,
  displayname,
  context,
  email,
  photoURL,
  createtime
) => {
  let router = useRouter();
  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid key={id} className="flex m-auto">
        <Card className="lg:w-full my-4">
          <p className="m-auto text-center">
            <Image
              className="m-auto text-center max-w-sm"
              height={300}
              width={300}
              src={downloadURL}
            />
          </p>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom component="div" className="w-3/5 text-xl ">
              {title}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
              {categori == "ONE PIECE" && (
                <p className="bg-blue-500 p-2 inline-block text-white text-center">
                  {categori}
                </p>
              )}
              {categori == "呪術廻戦" && (
                <p className="bg-purple-500 p-2 inline-block text-white text-center">
                  {categori}
                </p>
              )}
              {categori == "東京リベンジャーズ" && (
                <p className="bg-rose-500 p-2 inline-block text-white text-center">
                  {categori}
                </p>
              )}
              {categori == "キングダム" && (
                <p className="bg-yellow-500 p-2 inline-block text-white text-center">
                  {categori}
                </p>
              )}
              <br></br>

              {netabare == "ネタバレ有" && (
                <div>
                  <p className="bg-yellow-500 mt-2 p-1 inline-block text-white text-center">
                    {netabare}
                  </p>
                  <br></br>
                  <button
                    onClick={Opentext}
                    className="bg-yellow-500 mt-2 p-1 inline-block text-white text-center"
                  >
                    表示する
                  </button>
                  {opentext == true && <p className="">{context}</p>}
                </div>
              )}

              {netabare == "ネタバレ無" && (
                <p className="bg-blue-500 mt-2 p-1 inline-block text-white text-center">
                  {netabare}
                </p>
              )}

              <br></br>
              <div className="w-80 m-auto" style={styles}>
                {netabare == "ネタバレ無" && <p className="">{context}</p>}
              </div>

              <br></br>
              <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src={photoURL} />
              <p>{displayname}</p>
              <br></br>
              {createtime}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>

          {user.email == email && (
            <CardActions>
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                onClick={() =>
                  getID(data.id, data.name, data.age, data.title, data.context)
                }
              >
                更新する
              </Button>
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                onClick={() => deleteDocument(data.id)}
              >
                削除する
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          )}
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
#home.jsx
import省略

export default function Home() {
const省略

  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  // console.log(user);
  useEffect(() => {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem("Token");

    if (token) {
      getData();
    }
    if (!token) {
      router.push("/register");
    }
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    await getDocs(databaseRef).then((response) => {
      setFiredata(
        response.docs.map((data) => {
          return { ...data.data(), id: data.id };
        })
      );
    });
  };

  const getID = (
    id,
    name,
    age,
    title,
    context,
    downloadURL,
    categori,
    cratetime,
    displayname,
    netabare,
    photoURL,
    userid
  ) => {
    setID(id);
    setContext(context);
    setTitle(title);
    setName(name);
    setAge(age);
    setDisplayName(displayname);
    setDownloadURL(downloadURL);
    setIsUpdate(true);
    setCategori(categori);
    setCreatetime(cratetime);
    setNetabare(netabare);
    setPhotoURL(photoURL);
    setUserid(userid);
    console.log(title);
  };

記事の更新・削除の関数省略
 
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>漫画考察.net/ホーム画面</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <MuiNavbar />
      <br></br>
      <div className="max-w-7xl m-auto">
        <div className="lg:text-right text-center">
          <Button variant="outlined" className="">
            <Link href="/post">新規投稿をする</Link>
          </Button>
          {/* <Search /> */}
        </div>
        <h2 className="m-5 my-12 text-center text-2xl font-semibold">
          投稿一覧
        </h2>
        <p className="text-1xl text-center">投稿数　{firedata.length}件</p>

        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          {firedata.map((data) => {
            return (
              <Cardpost
                key={data.id}
                downloadURL={data.downloadURL}
                title={data.title}
                categori={data.categori}
                context={data.context}
                createtime={data.createtime}
                displayname={data.displayname}
                email={data.email}
              />
      
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

表示に成功した元ファイル

```
import省略

export default function Home() {
  const [ID, setID] = useState(null);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [context, setContext] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState(null);
  const [categori, setCategori] = useState("");
  const [firedata, setFiredata] = useState([]);
  const [createtime, setCreatetime] = useState("");
  const [isUpdate, setIsUpdate] = useState(false);
  const databaseRef = collection(database, "CRUD DATA");
  const [displayname, setDisplayName] = useState("");
  const [createObjectURL, setCreateObjectURL] = useState(null);
  const [downloadURL, setDownloadURL] = useState(null);
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState("");
  const [photoURL, setPhotoURL] = useState("");
  const [userid, setUserid] = useState(null);
  const [netabare, setNetabare] = useState("");
  const [opentext, setOpentext] = useState(false);
  const styles = { whiteSpace: "pre-line" };
  let router = useRouter();

  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  useEffect(() => {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem("Token");

    if (token) {
      getData();
    }
    if (!token) {
      router.push("/register");
    }
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    await getDocs(databaseRef).then((response) => {
      setFiredata(
        response.docs.map((data) => {
          return { ...data.data(), id: data.id };
        })
      );
    });
  };

  const getID = (
    id,
    name,
    age,
    title,
    context,
    downloadURL,
    categori,
    cratetime,
    displayname,
    netabare,
    photoURL,
    userid
  ) => {
    setID(id);
    setContext(context);
    setTitle(title);
    setName(name);
    setAge(age);
    setDisplayName(displayname);
    setDownloadURL(downloadURL);
    setIsUpdate(true);
    setCategori(categori);
    setCreatetime(cratetime);
    setNetabare(netabare);
    setPhotoURL(photoURL);
    setUserid(userid);
    console.log(title);
  };




  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>漫画考察.net/ホーム画面</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <MuiNavbar />
      <br></br>
      <div className="max-w-7xl m-auto">
        <div className="lg:text-right text-center">
          <Button variant="outlined" className="">
            <Link href="/post">新規投稿をする</Link>
          </Button>
          {/* <Search /> */}
        </div>
        <h2 className="m-5 my-12 text-center text-2xl font-semibold">
          投稿一覧
        </h2>
        <p className="text-1xl text-center">投稿数　{firedata.length}件</p>

        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          {firedata.map((data) => {
            return (
              <Grid key={data.id} className="flex m-auto">
                <Card className="lg:w-full w-4/5 my-4 m-auto">
                  <p className="m-auto text-center ">
                    <Image
                      className="m-auto text-center max-w-sm"
                      height={250}
                      width={250}
                      src={data.downloadURL}
                    />
                  </p>
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography
                      gutterBottom
                      component="div"
                      className="w-3/5 text-xl "
                    >
                      {data.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                      {data.categori == "ONE PIECE" && (
                        <p className="bg-blue-500 p-2 inline-block text-white text-center">
                          {data.categori}
                        </p>
                      )}
                      {data.categori == "呪術廻戦" && (
                        <p className="bg-purple-500 p-2 inline-block text-white text-center">
                          {data.categori}
                        </p>
                      )}
                      {data.categori == "東京リベンジャーズ" && (
                        <p className="bg-rose-500 p-2 inline-block text-white text-center">
                          {data.categori}
                        </p>
                      )}
                      {data.categori == "キングダム" && (
                        <p className="bg-yellow-500 p-2 inline-block text-white text-center">
                          {data.categori}
                        </p>
                      )}
                      <br></br>

                      {data.netabare == "ネタバレ有" && (
                        <div>
                          <p className="bg-yellow-500 mt-2 p-1 inline-block text-white text-center">
                            {data.netabare}
                          </p>
                          <br></br>
                          <button
                            onClick={Opentext}
                            className="bg-yellow-500 mt-2 p-1 inline-block text-white text-center"
                          >
                            表示する
                          </button>
                          {opentext == true && (
                            <p className="">{data.context}</p>
                          )}
                        </div>
                      )}

                      {data.netabare == "ネタバレ無" && (
                        <p className="bg-blue-500 mt-2 p-1 inline-block text-white text-center">
                          {data.netabare}
                        </p>
                      )}

                      <br></br>
                      <div className="w-80 m-auto" style={styles}>
                        {data.netabare == "ネタバレ無" && (
                          <p className="">{data.context}</p>
                        )}
                      </div>

                      <br></br>
                      <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src={data.photoURL} />
                      <p>{data.displayname}</p>
                      <br></br>
                      {data.createtime}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>

        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        {isUpdate && (
          <Box
            component="form"
            sx={{
              "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" },
            }}
            noValidate
            autoComplete="off"
          >
            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="タイトル（最大20文字)"
              variant="outlined"
              type="text"
              value={title}
              onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)}
            />

            <br></br>

            <TextField
              label="内容(最大500文字）"
              className="m-auto w-full"
              id="filled-multiline-static"
              multiline
              rows={14}
              type="text"
              value={context}
              onChange={(event) => setContext(event.target.value)}
            />
            <Button variant="outlined" onClick={updatefields}>
              更新する
            </Button>

            <br></br>
            {/* <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="名前(最大20文字）"
              variant="outlined"
              type="text"
              value={name}
              onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
            /> */}
            <br></br>
          </Box>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactのコンポーネント引数はPropsをObjectで受け取るのですが、質問に記載のコードではそうなっていないようです。`({})`で展開するのを想定しているのでしょう。

```
export const Cardpost = ({
  downloadURL,
  id,
  title,
  categori,
  netabare,
  displayname,
  context,
  email,
  photoURL,
  createtime
}) => {
```

こういった型のミスはTypeScript等を用いると防げます。

Comment: 回答して頂きありがとうございます。無事表示でき、勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @しゅんぺい 解決した場合、是非回答の左にあるチェックアイコンをクリックして回答を承認してください！ [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？ - ヘルプセンター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)